# Некорректно подключается второй монитор в Debian-based дистрибутивах Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, экран, монитор, radeon

Поставил новую Linux Mint. Попытался подключить второй монитор к ноутбуку (по vga). После попытки определить его - монитор подключается, если подтащить к краю экрана ноута окно - после определения край появляется на втором (как и должно работать при расширенных экранах), **но родной показывает черный экран**. 
Видеокарта - **amd radeon** 7520HD+проц amd-a6
пробовал ставить проприетарные дрова, но они видимо подходят только на древние версии
Пробовал на Debian 9 (ставил свободные дрова по гайду с сайта дебиана) , Linux Mint 19, Ubuntu 18 с KDE, Cinnamon и Mate. От смены системы и оболочки ситуация не менялась.

Вот логи `xorg` в момент подключения и вывод `xrandr` на Ubuntu 18 Mate:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

> ```
> [  1693.319] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
> [  1693.319] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
> [  1693.319] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
> [  1693.319] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
> [  3214.485] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3214.485] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3214.485] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3214.485] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3252.840] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3252.840] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3252.840] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3252.840] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3277.440] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3277.440] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3277.440] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3277.440] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3277.800] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3277.800] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3277.800] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3277.800] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3278.007] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3278.007] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3278.008] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3278.008] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3278.186] (II) RADEON(0): Allocate new frame buffer 2880x1024 stride 2880
> [  3278.193] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 216867K
> [  3304.351] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 5022
> [  3304.351] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3304.351] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  107.80  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (55.7 kHz eP)
> [  3304.351] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   71.87  1600 1648 1680 1936  900 903 909 928 -hsync -vsync (37.1 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "BNQ", prod id 30420
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x350"x0.0   25.17  640 656 752 800  350 387 389 449 +hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
> [  3318.252] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x864"x0.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
> [  3318.253] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x72.0  132.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1025 1028 1067 -hsync +vsync (76.8 kHz e)
> ```

```
xrandr
```

> ```
> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2880 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
>     LVDS connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
>        1600x900      60.00*+  40.00  
>        1440x900      59.99  
>        1280x854      59.95  
>        1280x800      59.96  
>        1280x720      59.97  
>        1152x768      59.95  
>        1024x768      59.95  
>        800x600       59.96  
>        848x480       59.94  
>        720x480       59.94  
>        640x480       59.94  
>     VGA-0 connected 1280x1024+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
>        1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02    72.05  
>        1152x864      75.00  
>        1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
>        832x624       74.55  
>        800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
>        640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
>        720x400       70.08  
>        640x350       70.07
> ```

Если под Debian будет проще продиагностировать - поставлю его (что-то говорили на форумах про Ubuntu).

И если пишете про `xorg` - приводите пожалуйста или полный конфиг файла, или объясните, как его инициализировать нормально - я слабо понимаю логику его работы. На дебиане пробовал - получилось что-то не то.

Первой системой стоит Windows 10 и на ней все отображается нормально.

На старой системе - Linux Mint 18 или всё работало или как-то этот вопрос удалось решить.

Answer (score 1):

Купил hdmi, выкинул vga - всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй расположить экраны один под другим. Некоторые видеокарты не могут выдать широкую картинку. в основном область ограниченна 4096*4096 на ноутбучных видюшках, но встречал и 2048*2048. при расположении один под другим  - показывает, а если рядом - гаснет.

Comment: Не помогает. На винде все нормально отображается.